# Android show two TimePickerDialog when pressing a button

Tags: android

is it possible to show two `TimePickerDialog` when clicking on a button. I want to show `TimePickerDialog` for `FROM` label and one `TimePickerDialog` for `TO` label.

I am creating application for football.

I found this howto: http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-create-time-picker-dialog-selecting-time-android

but is only for one TimePickerDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a layout with Two TimePicker widgets
- Use this layout with dialog.
- Add appropriate validations and you should be able to achieve what you need.